# Full Height/Width Image Grid

Tags: css, image, grid

I am trying to create a full width and full height image grid.
This is what I currently have: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYwMRo).

I am struggling with the variable height of the viewport.

Is there any way to do this?

The editor also forces me to write some more text in addition to my code, I don't know why but I have to. Really strange!

```css
html, body, ul {
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  background-color: blue;
}

a {
  line-height: 0;
  display: block;    
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to see what the question is. I don't see the problem in the code pen. Can you explain your question a little more?

Comment: I don't understand the question either, but flexboxes would allow you to fill an arbitrary space with a grid of images. Browser compatibility might be an issue though.

Comment: The Problem is, that I would like to have a grid of images which is 100% height and 100% width of the viewport on different screen-sizes. The grid should never be larger than the viewport (eg not scrollable).

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do.

```
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

`overflow:hidden` will hide anything that extends further than 100% of the element height.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJOPOy

This would work better and be more versatile if you made it dynamic with some javascript, but as long as you include enough image elements this will work fine and be able to fill most screens.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I might try this!

Answer (score 0):

I found a Solution myself:

The Problem is, that I have to use CSS-Background-Images instead of the img-Tag to fill the whole li-Element with my image.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azXxWj)

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

li {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    float: left;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/300x150);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```